# Flutter - type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> is not a subtype of type List<dynamic>

Tags: mysql, json, api, flutter

hello I creating a new flutter app , my database is a mysql database , my Json data is an array , i have tried to do the best I can but this error always pops up :

```
 type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> is not a subtype of type List<dynamic>
```

**Dataclass.dart**

```
class FolderList {
  final List<Data> data;

  FolderList({this.data});

  factory FolderList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return FolderList(
      data: json['folders'] != null ? (json['folders'] as List).map((i) => Data.fromJson(i)).toList() : null,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['folders'] = this.data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  final String id;
  final String name;

  Data({this.id, this.name});

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],

    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    return data;
  }
}
```

but when I try to decode the the json and parse it through the future function and the widget which here is the code

```
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final YearsMain value;


  SecondScreen({Key key, this.value}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  Future<List<FolderList>>fellowSubject() async{
    final jsonEndpoint =
        "http://msc-mu.com/api_verfication.php";

    final response = await http.post(jsonEndpoint,body: {
      'flag':'selectfellowsubjects',
      'parentsubject':widget.value.id
    });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List<dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
      return data;
    } else
      throw Exception('We were not able to successfully download the Main Subjects.');

  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    print(widget.value.id);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:  Center(
        child: new FutureBuilder<List<FolderList>>(
          future: fellowSubject(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              List<FolderList> fellow = snapshot.data;
              return ListViewFellow(fellow);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('${snapshot.error}');
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**ListViewFellow**

```
class ListViewFellow extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<FolderList> fellowSubject;
  ListViewFellow(this.fellowSubject);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int currentIndex) {
return createFellowItems(fellowSubject[currentIndex], context);
          },
      staggeredTileBuilder: (int currentIndex) =>
      new StaggeredTile.count(2, currentIndex.isEven ? 2 : 2),
      mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
    );
  }
  Widget createFellowItems(FolderList fellowData ,BuildContext context ){
    return GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xff131535),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child:
            (Text(fellowData.data[0].name))
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => new DownloadPage(
              value: fellowData,
            ),
          );

          Navigator.of(context).push(route);
        });
  }
}
```

I always get the above error I've tried everything but nothing worked for me at all , can any one come with a better solution ?

**Json Structure***

```
{
   "folders":[
      {
         "id":2107,
         "name":"Labs ",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":1,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-09-30 03:00:39",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2108,
         "name":"L1",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-09-30 03:00:45",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2130,
         "name":"L2",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-02
02:39:11",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2175,
         "name":"L3",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":1,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-07 03:43:15",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2202,
         "name":"L4",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-09 02:08:10",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2227,
         "name":"\u0645\u0631\u0627\u062c\u0639\u0627\u062a
",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":1,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-11 05:15:43",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2242,
         "name":"L5",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-14 03:45:24",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2257,
         "name":"L6",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-16
06:23:41",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2269,
         "name":"L7",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-21 03:39:12",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2309,
         "name":"L8",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-23 05:14:48",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2310,
         "name":"L8",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-23
05:14:51",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2346,
         "name":"L9",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-28 04:22:24",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2370,
         "name":"L10",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-30 03:02:00",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2446,
         "name":"L11",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-12
06:28:13",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2462,
         "name":"\u062a\u0628\u064a\u0636\u0627\u062a",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":1,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-13 08:39:00",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2464,
         "name":"L12",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-13
08:40:55",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2488,
         "name":"L13",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-18 06:09:11",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2490,
         "name":"L14",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-18 06:38:59",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2491,
         "name":"L15",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-18
06:45:57",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2497,
         "name":"\u062a\u0644\u062e\u064a\u0635\u0627\u062a",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":1,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-19 04:24:49",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2509,
         "name":"L16",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-20
09:56:04",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2522,
         "name":"L17",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-25 06:38:27",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2542,
         "name":"L18",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-27 12:19:12",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2552,
         "name":"Protein
Lab",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-27 16:32:27",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2562,
         "name":"Chromatography ",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-30 15:24:24",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2576,
         "name":"L19",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-02
02:05:29",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2580,
         "name":"L20",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-02 08:23:48",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2592,
         "name":"21",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-03 06:27:24",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2600,
         "name":"L22",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-04
06:22:46",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2614,
         "name":"L23",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-04 10:03:00",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2640,
         "name":"L24",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-08 06:53:11",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2644,
         "name":"L25",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-09
05:33:07",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2649,
         "name":"L26",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-09 07:58:42",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2711,
         "name":"\u0623\u0633\u0626\u0644\u0629",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-19
05:18:11",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      }
   ],
   "files":[
      {
         "id":4542,
         "name":"Ch2-part1.m4a 27.52MB",
         "img":null,
         "uploader":"Aws",
         "url":"http:\/\/msc-mu.com\/..\/uploaded\/031020190Ch2-part1.m4a",
         "createdate":"2019-10-03 09:53:39",
         "approved":1,
         "active":1
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show how the `JSON` structure looked like for `response.body` ?

Comment: can u point the line where code spits out the error?

Comment: the json is a map and not a List<String>. A map contains key-value pairs.

Comment: @Yadu i really dont know thats why iam asking here and android studio didn't show anything

Comment: @Uni so what should i do

Comment: where is the error pointing to? Which line is causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from here:
`List<dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);`.

The `body` of the JSON is a json object (map).
`json.decode(response.body)` will return a `Map` but you're trying to assign it a `List` thus raising that error.

You should do this:

```dart
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var data = json.decode(response.body); 

    return [FolderList.fromJson(data)];
} else
    throw Exception('We were not able to successfully download the Main Subjects.');
}
```

Comment: didnot work it says that i cant use a <FolderList> for a <List<FolderList>> type

Comment: Then you should `return [FolderList.fromJson(data)];`

Comment: iam rlly srry for the late reply but you helped me alot it shows now that type int is not a subtype of type string

Comment: The `id` filed in the json is an `int` but your data class accepts `String id`.
You should 1) change `String id` to `int id` OR 2) use `"${json['id']}"` in your `Data.fromJson` method

Comment: can i talk to you in discord ?

Comment: one last question is how to parse the data like name and id in text widget as a list ?

Comment: @Fahmi Sawalha you can upvote the answer if it helped. `fellowData.data[0].name)` should display the name.

Comment: i will recommend it as my answer , i have one problem that not every thing in the list is displayed i dont knwo why